# Streaming tweets to postgres; Unexplained partial selection of tweets

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, tweepy

I am not sure if I have a tweepy specific question, a psycopg2 specific question or just a regular python question.

I am trying to stream tweets from twitter and input them into a postgres database. It is working halfly. My first script prints a lot of tweets with a simple print statement of the tweets that I search.

```
import tweepy
import csv
import psycopg2
import sys

consumer_key = "xxx"
consumer_secret = "xxx"
access_token = "xxx"
access_token_secret = "xxx"

auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="*",since="2016-02-10", until="2016-02-29",count=100,geocode="5.29126,52.132633,150km").items(1000):
     print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8'), tweet.user.id, tweet.geo)
```

The last two lines I have replaced with the lines I put underneath. Then it only inputs a small partition of the tweets that are printed in the script above to my postgres table.

```
con = None 

try: 
    con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test' user='me'")   

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE Test")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Test(Id serial PRIMARY KEY, userid int, created int)")
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="*",since="2016-02-10", until="2016-02-29", count=100000, geocode="5.29126,52.132633,150km").items(10000000):
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8'), tweet.user.id, tweet.geo)
    test = ([tweet.user.id])
    print (test)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(userid) VALUES(%s)", (test))
    con.commit()

    print ( 'succes')
except:
    print ('well that is unfortunate')
```

I dont understand why it is only partially working. And my biggest problem is not knowing where to look: Postgres/psycopg2, tweepy or just regalur python.

Comment: could you provide a traceback? or it just doesn't work?

Comment: well it gives me like 13 records in the  table and then the except statement returns the message.

Comment: could you do in except statement:
```import traceback```


```print(traceback.print_exc())```( in two separate lines) and post results in the question

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....py", line 29, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(userid) VALUES(%s)", (test))
psycopg2.DataError: integer out of range

Comment: Thats it. Its so simple. Integer out of range. Thank you!